# Is Openshift internal registry required?

Tags: openshift

I'm working on an Openshift 3 cluster, trying to implement some CICD process. After experiencing some failures I figured out that the internal registry where my process is pushing the built images has no persistent storage allocated to it (using an emptyDir volume).

After some thoughts I decided to migrate to a solution using an external registry (Nexus) which is already integrated to the cluster.

The question is whether it would be fine in this case that the internal registry has no persistent storage allocated. More specifically, if I also use Image Streams to snapshot my Nexus images, will I need an internal registry with persistent storage?

Thank you!

Comment: If your internal registry is not using persistent storage, the cluster hasn't been set up correctly. How did you get that OpenShift cluster?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks for clarifying! The cluster was delivered to us by a vendor. They might have missed something during the setup.